# How to get ALL attributes of an HTMLElement from WebBrowser Component

Tags: c#, attributes, webbrowser-control

I am traversing the DOM using:

```
webBrowser.Document.Body.Parent.Children
```

I want to get all attributes of a specific `HTMLElement`. However, the `HTMLElement` just have a `getAttribute` method. I am looking for something more like `htmlelement.attributes[n]`. Because I dont know the attributes beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If wbMain is your WebBrowser1 control, do the following.

First, you need to get a ref to your element, lets say you want to access the first `<A>` link, of your page, you can loop through all if you want.

This is in VB, but its the same sort of thing in C#, just different syntax.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim aElement As HTMLAnchorElement = wbMain.Document.All.getElementByTagName("A")(0)

For i = 0 To aElement.attributes.length - 1
  MsgBox aElement.attributes.item(i).name & "=" & aElement.attributes.item(i).value
Next i
```

This will loop through all attributes and display it in a MSGBOX in a `name=value` format.

If you want to retreive it by name (attributes name) just call using `aElement.getAttribute("target")` to retreive the target attributes value from the a Link.

If you want to confirm you got the right object/element, just do a `aElement.outerHTML` to get the full HTML code for that element only.

Since I am using a pre.NET version, feel free to change the declaration from HTMLAnchorElement to IHTMLAnchorElement if it gives you trouble, of course, you can just use IHTMLElement if you want to go through all elements on a page, then all you'll need to do is wbMain.Document.All(0) for first element on a page, or loop until .All.length - 1 to go through all. Remember if you are using nested For loops, don't use i twice, use j for one of them :).

Let me know if this answers your question or if there is more I can do to help you with your issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse html doc in u r case u can use

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
   doc.Load(FileName);
   var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//NameofHtmlTag")[0];
   foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute attri in node.Attributes)
    {
       //iterate through attributes
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in this case I have to preserve the way IE parses the document. For that reason, I can't use HAP. I am looking for a solution using HTMLElement or unmanaged code in the worst case.

Comment: @Deveta HTMLAgilityPack is nasty, I wouldn't recommend using it.

Answer (score 0):

only know three non-`loop` methods so far. unfortunately, none seem to get ALL attr POSSIBLE on any given tag. alternatively, see attr-tag table at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

```
// if someTagID (t) is a jsObj -- note, needs JSON.stringify to print.
// tip: (x,null," ") args adds newlines per key-value pair for print.
var x = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(t)
JSON.stringify(x)

// else if (t) is an element via createElement, plain html etc -- see:
// NodeMap, name and value -- note, outputs to log only.
var x = t.attributes 
x.someAttr 
x.someAttr.value
// or Array -- note, no values without getAttribute()
var x = t.getAttributeNames()
t.getAttribute(x[n])
```

output to: a `var` and then page (print) or to `console` (log). 
All are plain js and work in es6 chrome and firefox. Unknown for others.